# how can I make a Json API which automatically saves pins to Pinterest

Tags: javascript, html, json, pinterest-api, extention-cli

I've been trying to create an API to automatically save pins without using mouse automation.

I've just been following a simple tutorial but it doesn't seem to apply to Pinterest.

https://youtu.be/xHGPBX5_lhw?si=21-API5T7uT4sNNm

can someone help me pls. It's 2024 Happy New Year BTW.

Comment: Which part of your code are you having an issue with?

Comment: document.querySelector('').click();

Comment: `'' is not a valid selector`

Comment: the one that is appropriate to select the element you want to target

Comment: I've tried nearly every selector in the inspector tab with out the '' but I still get error messages

Comment: I didn't say "without the ''` - I said using the code you posted in a comment results in an error stating that an empty selector is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.selenium.dev/
I managed to make a tinder bot while working with python before. I can't help you in detail because I don't have the slightest idea how to use Pinterest.